# How to not have truncated values in SSIS foreach

Tags: ssis

I have a foreach loop that loops over a result set from a sql task. It is truncating values to 255 but I don't know why.

[image]

I am looping over all rows in all the tables

[image]

The variable that is truncating is User::ProductRules

[image]

I am passing that to a script task. I have debugged this with a watch though and it's already truncated before passing the variable to the script, indicating it's a problem with the foreach loop.

Here are my variables:

[image]

The ProductRules variable is a string, so I don't see why it's being truncated.

Comment: Assume you double checked the results from the execute sql task and it's not truncated there?

Comment: what is the sql command used to populate the result set?